# emberjs load the model data with search

Tags: ember-cli

I have created a route, for search which is searching users, and the `application.hbs` is having the search form, below are the segments of my code.

**ROUTER** `router.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

export default Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('search', {path: '/search/:citySef/:group'});
});
```

**Route** `application.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      groups: this.store.find('group'),
      cities: this.store.find('city', {type: 'filled'})
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, models) {
    controller.setProperties(models);
  }
});
```

**Route** `search.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      users: this.store.find('user', {citySef: params.citySef, group: params.group})
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, models) {
    controller.setProperties(models);
  }
});
```

**Controller** `application.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  isProcessing: false,
  selectedCity: null,
  selectedGroup: null,

  actions: {
    submitSearch: function () {
      this.setProperties({
        isProcessing: true
      });

      var citySef = this.get("selectedCity");
      var group = this.get("selectedGroup");

      console.log(citySef, group);
      this.transitionToRoute('search', {citySef:citySef, group:group});
    }
  }
});
```

**Controller** `search.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
});
```

So basically I am creating a url like `localhost:4200/search/City/Group` to search users within a city with specific group.

When I press the search button, i can see that the URL is changed in the address bar from `localhost:4200` to `localhost:4200/search/City/Group` but it dont send request to server to get data from REST, but when i do refresh the page, then it loads the data.

**Edit**

I have included pretty much everything apart from templates.

**Edit** `2015-04-22`

I have uploaded the package (without bower and npm packages) to https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5slzmNBINvNMHNjcXdqNWlCeUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you put everything, including the templates, here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/?html,css,js,output

Comment: Its EMBER - CLI app so not sure how much I have to edit it, i have uploaded it to https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5slzmNBINvNMHNjcXdqNWlCeUk/view?usp=sharing you may need to add fixtures or create a rest api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Neha suggested, it was related to setupController

```
 setupController: function (controller, models) {
    if (models.citySef) {
      controller.set('model', this.store.find('user', {citySef: models.citySef, group: models.group}));
    } else {
      controller.set('content', models);
    }

  }
```

So when page loads it goes to else condition, and if i transitiontoroute it goes in if conditon. I think this can be cleaned but so far it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem in your case is model is not getting set properly first time.

Firstly you don't have to call  setupController function explicitly when you have model function in your route, since model hook handles all these settings.
But if you want then the convention should be like -

```
setupController:function(controller,models){
        controller.set('content',models);
   }
```

try using setup controller function in above pattern.

Comment: When I tried 'content' it stopped presenting me the data which was previously displaying on the page load, I can see the call is made but response is not displayed on refresh. and also search functionality is same.

Comment: can you try just model method and no setupcontroller and can you also try without RSVP.hash. since you have only one parameter to return then hash is not required.

Comment: I removed the RSVP.hash and updated template, it worked same like before, I removed setupController and got `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed {citySef: Lahore, group: An}` error when I hit the search button. Reloading the page is loading the content from REST